# Typo3 upgrade from 6 to 7 workspace page not found

Tags: typo3

we need to upgrade our version of typo3 from 6 to 7.
I have tried the migration in a test lab cloned from production.
We use workspaces and the site is running from a path inside the apache DocumentRoot  (DocumentRoot/pag/)
After the migration I have a problem with staging in workspaces.
In typo backend if I dx click on the article and select "show" I get a "page   not found error" because on the path it duplicates the pag prefix.

This is an example of wrong url http://myhost.example.com/pag/pag/typo3/index.php?M=web_WorkspacesWorkspaces&moduleToken=1ff8d78f52146b2c19a40a7a8232844f3a3eb668&tx_workspaces_web_workspacesworkspaces%5Baction%5D=index&tx_workspaces_web_workspacesworkspaces%5Bcontroller%5D=Preview&id=11593&ADMCMD_cooluri=1

If I remove the repeated "pag" from the url it works
If I dx clic on the article in the live workspace it works.
So it is related only to the staging workspace.

Can someone help me to address this issue?

Thank you

Comment: once you clear all realurl cache data and check again may be realurl caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use tx_realurl extension? if so disable `tx_realurl_enable = 0` in your Provider Extension config.t3s file. and empty in your database the tx_realurl indexer tables. Maybe something went wrong there after the TYPO3 Update.